# In Codesys, how to define pre-processors parameters?

Tags: plc, codesys, structured-text, iec61131-3

I need create certain amount of ***struct*** ***type*** pairs which will be further used as ***const*** parameters and has essentially the same set of values, but scaled in half, something like this (given a  ***n*** constant):

```
TYPE ADDR_1 :
    STRUCT  
        PARAMETER_A:    INT :=0;
        PARAMETER_B:    INT :=2;
        PARAMETER_C:    INT :=4;
        - - - 
        PARAMETER_n:    INT :=n; (* being n any number *)
    END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

And the correlate pair:

```
TYPE ADDR_2 :
    STRUCT  
        PARAMETER_X:    INT :=0/2;
        PARAMETER_Y:    INT :=2/2;
        PARAMETER_Z:    INT :=4/2;
        - - - 
        PARAMETER_n/2:  INT :=n/2;  (* being n any number *)
    END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

By creating both structs sepparately it works pretty well, I use them to create a ***CONST*** array to be used at the ***SWITCH...CASE*** statement - which as we know well, only accepts constants at their indexes, not variables.

However every change made in one structure has to be refactored in another structure, indeed not a safe approach in therms of 'best practices' designing.

The problem which I'm facing now, is that if I create ***CONST*** values at the Global Variable List (GVL), it has not precedence in compilation timeline, I mean, structs are evaluated first.

Another option were by using ***Pragmas***, but it works only within a specific scope, which mean it would not act as 'global parameters'.

I just wanted define each above parameter before compilation in such a way I could define just once, by dividing one by other by 2.

Comment: > However every change made in one structure has to be refactored in another structure, indeed not a safe approach in terms of 'best practices' designing. How those are constants then if you make changes there?

Comment: Are you using Codesys 2 or 3?

Comment: I tested your setup with Twincat 3 (which uses the Codesys 3 compiler) and a constant from a GVL and had no compilation errors.

Comment: Hi @Filippo, I`m using Codesys 3

Comment: Hi @Sergey, I referred to "changes" in the context of the programming phase, not in runtime. I wanted to say that, if for example I add parameters in one structure, I need to add in another structure aswell, having the same (x2) scale, If I made mistake in this calculation, this will represent a weakeness on the current approach.

Comment: Hi @Filippo, I used TwinCAT3 some time ago, and once it is based on the "Visual Studio IDE" there are lot of resources available there. Anyway, I was not referring to the above structure pair as the issue, but rather the lack of a way to create a 'global' preprocessor directive parameter (similar to ***#define***) which would be used in both structures above.

Comment: So you are not having an issue with "n" and "n" being a constant global variable?

Comment: You said "The problem which I'm facing now, is that if I create CONST values at the Global Variable List (GVL), it has not precedence in compilation timeline, I mean, structs are evaluated first." But that is not correct, you can build your Struct with a predifined global constant and the value will be assigned at compile time..

Comment: You can define first structure in CONSTANT scope and other in global vars only using constant as a base for the division.

Comment: I would say that the solution would be something using both features both you recommended; The **EXTENDS** in particular is something that did not came to mind until now, it seems promising. As per the use of Global Variable it could not be done this way; note that as said, this structure will be used as the index of a **switch...case** arrangement, and only consts are allowed as indexes. (I will update this thread as long I make progress on this regard)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use constant global variables, but just "defines" as in C, then use *Pragmas*.

If you want your Pragma to have a global scope you can either put it in a global variable list or use inheritance instead. Here an inheritance example:

```
TYPE ST_Root :
STRUCT
    {IF defined (test) }
        n : INT := 1;
    {ELSE}
        n : INT := 2;
    {END_IF}
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE


TYPE ST_Derived EXTENDS ST_Root :
STRUCT
    x : INT := n + 1;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

Comment: You should use enums for the indexes of your switch case.In your case just use IF..ELSIF statements.

Answer (score 0):

You will need only one structure.

```
TYPE ADDR :
    STRUCT  
        PARAMETER_A:    INT :=0;
        PARAMETER_B:    INT :=2;
        PARAMETER_C:    INT :=4;
    END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

First, define base as constant. That will create it first.

```
VAR_GLOBAL CONSTANT
    MyADR: ADDR := (PARAMETER_A := 0, PARAMETER_B := 2, ...);
END_VAR
```

Then create other global variables.

```
VAR_GLOBAL
    MyADRBy2: ADDR := (
        PARAMETER_A := MyADR.PARAMETER_A / 2, 
        PARAMETER_B := MyADR.PARAMETER_A / 2,
    ...);
END_VAR
```

Comment: You can also just declare a global constant instead of a constant struct instance.